# single line bash function with a for loop

Tags: bash, docker, loops

This bash function allows me to run any command X number of times:

```
run() {
    number=$1
    shift
    for i in `seq $number`; do
      $@
    done
}
```

My problem is I need to add this to a docker shell. I think the easiest way would be to add it to the image on which the shell is made by adding the function definition to a RUN command in the DockerFile. But it won't accept the multiple lines. Adding "\" at the end of each (except the last) doesn't work and no combination of line breaks helps. I also tried eliminating the back-ticks - no luck.

So I thought: "That's fine - I'll just make it a one-liner." And nothing I do or try gets the syntax right for doing that either.

Can someone help me make this a single-line definition OR help me get the DockerFile to accept this as multiple lines?

Comment: What's your final goal with this?  You _could_ define a shell function in a `RUN` command (the answers give one-line syntax) but it will become undefined at the end of this `RUN` line.  Just using `for i in $(seq 10); do foo; done` without the shell function might be a little easier for build-time use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function definition as a one-liner:

```
run () { number=$1 ; shift ; for i in `seq $number` ; do $@ ; done }
```

Whether it works for docker is a different question, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write it as :

```
run () { number=$1;shift; for i in `seq $number`;do echo $number; done }
```

Another way can be to write this function in a `script.sh` file and then simply copy this into the docker and then do a:

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "source script.sh; run 3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

What causes the syntax error? Try to change it like so for example.

```
run() { N=$1; shift; while [[ $N -gt 0 ]]; do $@; ((N--)); done; }
```